# Android Layout elements left to right then below according to screen size

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-gridview, android-relativelayout, android-gridlayout

I have many equally size elements in one layout, I need to order them from left to right in one row and continue in the second row if the screen size is not enough.
I tried LinearLayout as below but this is working fine for xxlarge screens. however for small screen it's showing first three elements only and rest are cropped.
same with RelativLayout using `toRightof & toEndOf` .
I think this can be done using a grid view, but there must be a simpler way.
Your suggestions please

```
<LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"

            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_30sdp">

            <include layout="@layout/element1" />
            <include layout="@layout/element2" />
            <include layout="@layout/element3" />
            <include layout="@layout/element4" />
            <include layout="@layout/element5" />
            <include layout="@layout/element6" />


        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: grid view is the solution. But recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager is always a better option.

Comment: can u put other xml file also?

Comment: you can use google flexbox-layout for this. https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: @krishna, each element is a linearlayout cotaining button & textview nothing more.

Comment: @kartik, I will try flexbox, hope it solve the problem. will let you know

Comment: @ kartik malik. It's ok .flexbox is very powerfull layout. please put your  comment in the answer so I accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **nested** LinearLayout
let the outer LinearLayout be with **vertical** orientation and include in it 3 LinearLayouts that have **horizontal** orientation